# Connect android contact apps with sms and phone call

Tags: java, android

I am now writing a contact application for android as my term project. I managed to write the code for adding, editing and deleting contacts. Now I wish to connect my contact app with sms and phone call. When user click on the envelope symbol at the side of a contact, the user would be directed to the SMS application of the phone. I have no idea how to write the code to bridge the contact app with the SMS and calling. Help please.

Comment: you can easily do that using intent search google. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redirecting to SMS application, you can use :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"));
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
```

For making a phone call, you can use :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:12125551212"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure you add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```